# ¿Qué palabras se derivan del verbo en latín "emo, emere"?

Tags: etimología, solicitud-de-término, latín

En mi estudio de latín, una forma que uso para aprender el significado de palabras en latín es relacionarlas con el significado de palabras relacionadas (derivadas) en español. Afortunadamente, son muchas las que están relacionadas. Empero, algunas lo están de forma menos evidente.

Mi pregunta tiene que ver con el verbo en latín *[emo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emo#Latin)*, cuyo significado más común es "comprar". Según [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comprar#Spanish), el verbo español "comprar" viene del latín *comparare*, que significa "comparar" (y derivó en el verbo homonimo en español). ¿Hay alguna palabra en español derivada del verbo *emo*, con un significado relacionado al del latín? No puedo pensar en ninguna.

Answer (score 7):

No parece haber ninguna palabra derivada directamente del latín *emo, emere*, pero sí que hay alguna de derivados suyos. Ejemplos:

- ***[Premio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U1UcgqD)***, derivada de *[praemium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praemium#Latin)*, formada por *prae-* ("antes") + *emō* ("comprar, obtener"). Entiendo entonces que un "premio" es literalmente algo que consigues "antes de tener que comprarlo".
- ***[Eximir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HFfoJkc)***, derivada de *[eximo, eximĕre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eximo#Latin)*, formada por *[ex-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex-#Latin)* ("fuera" o "privación") + *emō* ("comprar, obtener"). Entiendo entonces que "eximir" es "liberar de la obligación de adquirir", tal vez.
- ***[Redimir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VYpI2LB)***, derivada de *[redimo, redimĕre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redimo#Latin)*, formada por *[red-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/red-#Latin)* ("de nuevo") + *emō* ("comprar, obtener"). Entiendo entonces que "redimir" es "volver a comprar".

Otras palabras que han tenido un viaje más largo:

- ***[Asumir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=47S4L2q)***, que viene de *[assūmō, assūmere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assumo#Latin)*, este de *ad-* y *[sūmō, sūmere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sumo#Latin)* (verbo con una variedad de significados: "asumir", "tomar", "comprar", "pedir prestado" y otros), y este de *sub-* y *emō*.
- ***[Resumir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WFYe5Ne)***, con una ruta similar: de *[resūmō, resūmere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resumo#Latin)* ("reanudar", "recuperar"), y este de *re-* y *[sūmō, sūmere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sumo#Latin)*.

Answer (score 5):

En adición a los ejemplos de Charlie, hay los siguientes formados con prefijos:

- [dimir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DnZXPOf) ← demo ← dē- +‎ **emō** <sup>(via Asturian)</sup>
  <sub>(dumir)</sub>
- dirimir ← dirimo ← dis- +‎ **emō**
- perimir ← perimo ← per + **emō**
- exento ← exemptus ← eximo ←  ex- +‎ **emō**
- ejemplo ← exemplum ← eximo ←  ex- +‎ **emō**
- sumir ← sumo ← *susmō ← *sups(e)mō ← sub- +‎ **emō**
  <sub>([asumir,] reasumir, consumir, insumir, presumir, [resumir,] subsumir)</sub>

Comment: Ejemplo? Como se relaciona con _emo_?

Comment: @luchonacho emo (to acquire) > ex + emo (to acquire out of) > eximo (to extract) > exemplum (a sample > an example)

Comment: Interesante! Es esa derivacion una opinion generalizada?